# Displaying object issues in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am assigning axios request error in my errors data and if I console it it shows the error if exist. Without username and email it consoles `{"username":["The username field is required."],"email":["The email has already been taken."]}.` But if I display it in div section it shows me nothing. This is my errors data:

```
data(){
      return{
          form:{
            username:null,
            email:null,
            password:null,
          },
          errors:{}
      }
    }, 

methods:{
      register(){
        axios.post('/api/admin/register/',this.form).
          then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data.token);
            if(res.data.token){
              this.$router.push({name:'login_admin'})
            }else{
              this.$router.push('/');
            }
          })//
          .catch(error => {
                         (this.errors )= error.response.data;
                       console.log(this.errors);
                    }); 
            
        
      }
    }
}
<small class="text text-danger" v-if="errors.email">I{{errors.email}}</small>
```

Errors is displaying if i define errors in console.log but errors.email not consoling so the erros.email not getting the v-if tag. How can I solve this?

Comment: The code is ok. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. In case it's specific to api response, mock it with the expected object. It's unclear what happens, in one place you state "Without username and email it consoles", in another "but errors.email not consoling". So is email is shown in a console or not?

Comment: email is not shown in console

Comment: The type of this.errors is returned not as object but as string. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The errors returned as object so I converted the error data to object and the problem fixed it. `this.errors = JSON.parse(err.response.data)`

Comment: This is the problem with your api or axios config. If the response is valid JSON, there's never a need to parse it. It's already parsed